# Can a Guardian (parent) force a 17 year old to move out of their house in Colorado?

Tags: civil-law, minor

My Father, who has custody of me, has threatened to force me to move out of his house. If I am 17, and live in Colorado can he make me move out?

He doesn't seem to care who I move in with but I think he is assuming I'll move in with my Mom (who does not have legal custody)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are not legally emancipated. To evict anyone, there is a legal process – nobody can just kick a tenant out, without the appropriate court order. [These guys](http://columbinelaw.com/2018/02/05/evicting-your-adult-child/) describe the process for evicting an *adult* child (where the child does not have a lease and is a tenant at will). A custodial parent has a legal obligation to provide, among other things, a place for the child to live. Kicking a child out is contrary to that obligation, and could constitute child abandonment ("neglect" under [CRS 19-3-102](https://law.justia.com/codes/colorado/2016/title-19/article-3/part-1/section-19-3-102)), and that is a crime. A court would not grant a parent's motion to evict a minor child. If a landlord takes the law into his own hands, as it were, he can be sued under [CRS 38-12-510](https://codes.findlaw.com/co/title-38-property-real-and-personal/co-rev-st-sect-38-12-510.html).

Comment: "These guys" link is dead, and a valid image does not exist on archive.org.